# how to introduce delay when computer and player collide?

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

Basically, when the computer and player collide, at the moment, I have tried to make the player and computer's velocity opposite of what they are when they collide. Which worked before, however this doesn't work now, as it seems the player and computer player get stuck even when both of their velocity's have changed.

As I think it's due to the amount of times the update method, etc are checked per frame, so the velocity it constantly changing.

So I just want to change it when the player and computer have collided and not keep changing it whilst they are colliding.

EDIT: link to video showing the problem (youtube.com/watch?v=oON4s2SRtso)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you detect a collision you don't have to change only computer and player velocity, but you need to change their position, too.
For example, subtract the velocity vector (as it was the previous frame), in order to ensure that computer and player are not colliding. In this way, when you change their velocity they won't get stuck, and the velocity will change only once.

**EDIT**

When a collision occurs between your moving player and ball you have to temporarily set 0 its speed and then change the ball position:

```
computerPlayer.Position.X = player.Position.X + offset
```

where `offset` is the distance from the origin of your player to the border of your collider.
When you stop moving the player you invert the previous ball velocity (before you set it 0), making it bounce and go off form you.

Comment: at the moment, i basically detect if there is a collision, using rectangles, i.e. does boundingbox of player and computer intersect, then i test to see if the left side of the comp. box is >= player's bounding box left side, so when they collide, the physics can be different for each side, to be more realistic.

So... now i have 

computerPlayer.Position.X = -computerPlayer.Velocity.X;

instead of computerPlayer.Velocity.X = -computerPlayer.Velocity.X;

i have also done this for the player as well... know what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: You have to do both subtracting the velocity from position and inverting the velocity.

Comment: ok, i think this works, however if the player is pressing the left arrow key down, then the player and comp get stuck, as they are still colliding, so i have tried to make it so that if the left key is pressed and player and comp have collided, the player velocity = 0, so that they dont get stuck and then when collided, the comp player has a chance to bounce off the player and not get trapped between an invisible wall and the player.... any ideas of how to do this, as my solutions haven't worked so far... thanks v much :)

Comment: Why are they still colliding? I can't understand why this happens only when pressing the left arrow key.

Comment: im not sure either, i'm assuming due to the speed of the computer player, as it's checked 60 times a second, within that time, they are still colliding... i think... so i want them to just collide once and thats it... i have also tried using the boundingbox.Top, etc to make the physics a bit more realistic as u would expect it... but i think that's another problem...

Comment: A solution could be what *SchautDollar* wrote, a bool that you use as a "flag", ensuring you to check the collision only once. The important thing is that, when you detect a collision, you change directions and positions of your objects to a state where they aren't colliding anymore.

Comment: yea, sorry i forgot to mention i am using boolean(s), well i used one at first to test exactly this and when collided = true, i altered positions, etc, however i think if the computer is moving towards the player and the player isn't moving, when they collide its fine, its just when both the player and computer and moving towards each other, they collide, however as they seem to get stuck, as maybe they are colliding several times in that frame, so the velocity alternates (as i have observed), therefore the computer gets stuck as i mentioned... but maybe if i set.....

Comment: ..... a boolean like SchautDollar mentioned, so poss. have 2 booleans, collided and colliding, and check if they are still colliding, if so, DONT change the velocity, etc .... i think i will try that... thanks

Comment: That's weird, if you detect a collision (anyway both object are moving or not), subtracting the velocity will "divide" the moving objects, preventing the stuck situation. Then you invert their velocities as usual, making them "bounce".

Comment: i have just posted a video if this problem, as i have been trying for hours today and for a long time before today and some solutions are better than others, however this is still a problem that exists with all of them... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oON4s2SRtso

Oh btw, it seems that this error occurs most likely when a key is pressed down, so it the ball hits the player on the left side and the left key is pressed, so moving into the collision, the error occurs... thanks for all the help btw

Comment: Maybe your problem is that your player's velocity (when pressing a key) is greater than the ball speed, so when detecting a collision and inverting ball speed that movement is not enough to go out from the player's collider. Another problem is that if you collide with a ball that's moving in the same direction of your player the collision inverts its velocity, causing it to go towards the player, and inside its collider. Isn't it?

Comment: :D:D ... i think you are absolutely correct here pinckerman!...

When i changed the velocity of the player to equal the computers when the left key is pressed, it seems to work perfectly... this being said, what i wanted to do was make the player a bit quicker than the computer, so maybe if there's a collision, i could temporarily change the player's velocity to equal the computer's, so this problem doesn't occur again... i am having the same prob now when jumping, however i should be able to fix it as you have given me the solution.... i can't thank you enough for this...

Comment: ok, so i can't slow down the player on collision to prevent the previous problem from occur, nor can i measure the length between them and just before they collide, slow the player down, which is a bit annoying tbh and limits me atm as to what i can do with the game, however you did solve my inital problem, so thanks again and i will accept your answer indeed lol :D

Comment: Thanks! Anyway, if you want to have the player faster than other objects you need to move the ball position outside the player's collider everytime you detect a collision, I think it's the only way.

Comment: No problem :D... and sorry i'm not too sure what you mean, i have tried to change the speeds of both player and computer when a collision occurs, however this doesnt work...

Comment: I mean that, when your player collides with a ball, you should "push" that ball (because you're faster than it). When your player is moving and a collision occurs, the ball velocity become 0 temporarily, but you change its position with your player. When your player stops the ball moves again.

Comment: Yea, i have tried to in effect move the computer ball when the player collides with it, so computerPlayer.Velocity.Y += player.Velocity.Y...

this sort of works, however if the ball is really close to the player and then the player jumps, it still gets stuck.... i have tried using a while statement, etc but still doesn't work, so i inverse the computers velocity = doesnt work, try to move the computer at the speed and direction of the player = doesn't work (even when don't make player's velocity 0)... i wonder if you know of maybe vector2 length to try to predict if comp is approaching player

Comment: I can't understand why you are changing Y component of your speed, and why you are adding them.

Comment: Oh, i was altering the Y value, as i was working on the collision of the comp player when it hits the top of the player, as the left and right side collision's of the player seem to work, its mainly the collision when the comp hits the player from the top and underneath

Comment: If your player moves only sideways you shouldn't have problems to handle that case.

Comment: Yea but i want my player to be able to jump... the code i have atm which is causing problems, due to the same reason you mentioned before (the player's speed > the computer's speed) is:
<code>
    pPosition.Y -= 5f;
    pVelocity.Y = -8f;
</code>

Comment: I think it's easier if you change positions while colliding and jumping, and then change velocities.

Answer (score 0):

From what I've gotten from your comments and question, you could keep track of when the objects collide. When they collide, just set a boolean reminding you that the objects have collided. Everytime you check for collisions, just reset the boolean. An example sudo code

```
bool collision = false;

void CheckCollision(){
    colliding = /* Colliding() */;
    if(colliding  && !collision){
        collision = true;      
        //Manipulate directions, locations, etc.   
    }        
    else if(!colliding ){ //No collision

        collision = false;
    }
}

bool Colliding(){
    return colliding;
}
```

There are several ways of going about this. This is just one. This solution probably doesn't scale very well, but for something small, it works.

Comment: sorry, i forgot to mention i am actually using a boolean and now i'm using several, so maybe i may have got a bit caught up in all the boolean's i am using... and i actually set collided to false if they dont intersect... thanks anyway

Comment: @6a6179 Thanks for the update! I'm sure you will figure it out, if you don't just update your question and I'll update my answer if I can still help.

Comment: i have just posted a video (youtube.com/watch?v=oON4s2SRtso) on this problem, as i have been trying for hours today and for a long time before today and some solutions are better than others, however this is still a problem that exists with all of them... Oh btw, it seems that this error occurs most likely when a key is pressed down, so it the ball hits the player on the left side and the left key is pressed, so moving into the collision, the error occurs... thanks for all the help btw